# Content box, padding and window resize

Tags: html, css

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymggLtv1/)

I have an image, I need to exclude the padding from it's size.

I use:

```
    box-sizing: content-box;
```

The problem is, that when I resize the browser, I expect the image to shrink in size. With the above content box, the image does not shrink when the browser is resized as expected. Resizing only happens after the browser has been dragged in past all of the padding. This means half the image goes off screen.

Is there a way to use content box, padding and still have the image resized when the browser resizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set to the width the correct value using a calc expression

```css
img{
  box-sizing: content-box;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  background: green;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/flickr/2746960560_8711acfc60_o.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you want this:

https://jsfiddle.net/g47u1hop/

```
img{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  background: green;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You can use box-sizing: border-box

Or you can use media queries to control you image size

Comment: Thanks, needs to be content box unfortunately - due to a jquery plugin calculating width on the image.